# Postmarkapp not sending emails

Tags: php, api, email, json

I am trying to send email from my postmarkapp api using php and I am getting the following error:

> The JSON response from Postmark:
>
> Array
>   (
>       [ErrorCode] => 400
>       [Message] => Sender signature not defined for From address.
>   )
>
> The HTTP code was: 422

How do I solve this? I am using this [function](http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2013/02/sending-emails-with-postmark-and-php/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Postmark requires you to set up a sender signature.

http://support.postmarkapp.com/customer/portal/articles/64739-what-is-dkim-and-spf-and-why-should-i-use-it-

> To get started, login to your account and add a new Sender Signature. For each sending domain, we will provide the proper instructions for creating DKIM and SPF records in your DNS.